# How to check if another iPhone using the same program is in your vicinity?

Tags: ios, geolocation, gps

I've been googling this problem, but haven't gotten the wording right.

Basically I'm looking for an API, or some seeds of guidance in how I would go about writing a program where you get push notified if someone is in the same area as you based on GPS coordinates.  In short: a realtime 4square not based on checking-in but based on GPS.

Part of me feels like this is something Apple may frown upon, but if the user is notified and making the decision to run the app, perhaps not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the Bluetooth Bonjour type notifications found in GameKit. This has nothing to do with GPS and is instead based of short range radio (Bluetooth) which advertises itself using a zero conf protocol. The APIs basically give you the ability to broadcast your service (eg. "MyGame") over bluetooth and listen for others potentially broadcasting the same service.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about geographic vicinity, you'll need to set up a central server where each device can register its location, and which will provide locations of nearby devices. A service like FourSquare does exactly this kind of thing.

Another way to look at 'vicinity' is network vicinity. You could have each device advertise itself via Bonjour and look for other devices doing the same.

Comment: I want it to be real time.  For instance, Person A walks into a bar, that Person B is at.  They both get a notification that they're running MyApp.  Person A leaves the bar and walks down the street, where he gets a notification that Person C is hanging out at the bus stop that Person A is walking by and also using MyApp.